# Ubuntu 16.04 Eclipse Oxygen + GlassFish = falls eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, glassfish-4

On Ubuntu 16.04 I have installed Eclipse Oxygen and the GlassFish Tools.

During the steps on picture Eclipse is shooting down without any message:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is something shown in the _Error Log_ view?

Comment: 1. The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.  2.already installed: org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.jonas4   - only this message in Error log